# What is the R equivalent of python base64.urlsafe_b64decode(client_secret)?

Tags: python, r, encryption

I'm trying to do a hash so that I can authenticate against the google api.

If I run `base64.urlsafe_b64decode(client_secret)?` where client_secret is my key and then use that in R in digest:hmac, everything works.

However, I can't find the b64decode?

**Regarding comment below:**

I admit I'm somewhat of a beginner, but here is an example. Note that I made up the secret_key here as obviously I can't share the real one publicly.

In Python:

```
base64.urlsafe_b64decode("49ugdj9v_3290k3r902qkf9=")
Out[35]: '\xe3\xdb\xa0v?o\xff}\xbd\xd2M\xeb\xf7M\xaa\x91\xff'
```

Note: The result above is exactly the string that I want.

In R:

```
RCurl::base64("49ugdj9v_3290k3r902qkf9=", encode = FALSE)
[1] "\xe3۠v?o\003}\xbd\xd2M\xeb\xf7M\xaa\x91\xff"
```

Notice that the result is not the same. Also, I tried doing:

```
> URLencode(RCurl::base64("49ugdj9v_3290k3r902qkf9=", encode = FALSE))
[1] "NA"
Warning message:
In strsplit(URL, "") : input string 1 is invalid in this locale
```

If I try a different base64 encoder in R, I get the same thing:

```
rawToChar(base64decode("49ugdj9v_3290k3r902qkf9="))
[1] "\xe3۠v?o\xdfot\x93z\xfd\xd3j\xa4\177"
```

Anyway, I hope this helps explain my trouble. If anyone has a solution, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @hrbrmstr: yep, i've tried that -- it doesn't give the correct value...

Comment: Why don't you include a clear [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Include sample input data and the desired output for that input. Do you just not know how to do any sort of base64 encoding? Show the R code you've tried running.

Comment: @MrFlick: As requested, I've made an example above. Thank you for looking.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not. I am following the example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth#signature_examples

I tried looking at some of the others but I can't seem to get the function to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a "url-safe" encode, you convert `/` to `_` and `+` to `-`. So in order to properly decode the the values, you need to undo these translations first.

```
urlsafebase64becode <- function(x, ...) {
     RCurl::base64(gsub("_","/", gsub("-","+",x,fixed=TRUE),fixed=TRUE), encode=FALSE, ...)
}

urlsafebase64becode("49ugdj9v_3290k3r902qkf=")
urlsafebase64becode("49ugdj9v_3290k3r902qkf=", mode="raw")
#  [1] e3 db a0 76 3f 6f ff 7d bd d2 4d eb f7 4d
```

which seems to match the Python

```
' '.join(x.encode('hex') for x in base64.urlsafe_b64decode("49ugdj9v_3290k3r902qkf9="))
'e3 db a0 76 3f 6f ff 7d bd d2 4d eb f7 4d aa 91 ff'
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Seems to work -- I wish this existed in an R package directly...

Comment: In case anyone needs the encode function, I provide it here for completeness:

`urlsafebase64encode <- function(x, ...) {
  gsub("+","-",gsub("/","_",RCurl::base64(x,encode =TRUE), fixed = TRUE), fixed = TRUE)
}`